# Getting started with MetroJS

Tags: jquery, html

A rarely venture into jquery but stumbled across Metro JS http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs I was quite impressed with it so thought I would give it a go. I like to keep things simple. Being no jquery expert I can't seem to get the flip tile working so any help would be appreciated. My full code is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="metrojs.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="metrojs.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //animate on click

    var $tile1 = $("#tile1").liveTile();
    $("#tile1").on("click", function(){
        $("#tile1").liveTile('play', 0);
    });

    var $tile2 = $("#tile2").liveTile();
    $("#tile2").on("click", function(){
        $("#tile2").liveTile("play", 0);
    });

    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".live-tile,#tile1,#tile2").liveTile();
            });
        </script>


    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Animate on Click</h1>
    <div class="tiles red">
        <div class="live-tile" id="tile1" data-mode="flip">        
            <div>
                <a class="full" href="#">front</a>
                <span class="tile-title">front title</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>this tile flips once vertically when clicked using a repeat count of 0</p>
                <span class="tile-title">back title</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="live-tile blue" id="tile2" data-direction="horizontal" data-mode="flip">     
            <div>front
                  <span class="tile-title">front title</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>this tile flips horizontally on an interval or when when clicked
                   <span class="tile-title">back title</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to include jQuery in order for metro.js to work.

You can downloaded the latest version of jQuery [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js). Save it in the same folder as the rest of your code, and add the line:

```
<script src="jquery.2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure to put this line BEFORE you include `metrojs.js` -- you need to load jQuery before loading metro.js.

---

In the future, you can debug this by opening up the web console, which will report any Javascript errors that occur on a webpage, in addition to tons of other useful info. In this case, running your webpage caused the console to report that `jQuery` and `$` were undefined, which helped me identify the problem.

Instructions on accessing the web/debug console as well as other useful developer tools for Firefox, Chrome, and IE are available online.

Comment: Thanks loads, thats solved one problem and now given me another. I wanted the tiles to flip on "click" but now they just flip randomly. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user985197 -- it looks like the code you provided is set up to flip the red tile only when it's clicked, and flip the blue tile on an interval or when clicking. If you look at the JS code embedded in the page, it sets up `$tile1` and `$tile2` differently. If you can set up `$tile2` in the same way as `$tile1`, I believe it should do what you want.

Comment: I have updated the code above. If you see both tiles are set the same. But they still both flip randomly and do not respond to "click"